# jQuery parseJSON fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I was doing some stuff with jQuery parseJSON function.

This is the code, which is not working

```
var obj = $.parseJSON("{'w':'w-1'}");
alert(obj.w);
```

After debugging for some time I changed the single quotes to double quotes like the code below and it worked fine.

```
var obj = $.parseJSON('{"w":"wb-001"}');
alert(obj.w);
```

Some related Questions

1) I just want to know WHY single quotes don't work?

2) Single quotes works fine with eval but not with parseJSON, Why?

```
var obj = eval("("+"{'w':'w-1'}"+")");
alert(obj.w);
```

3) I usually write like this

```
var someString = "HELLO WORLD";
```

and

```
var someString = 'HELLO WORLD';
```

After encountering the above problem I was wondering if I was doing something wrong in all my past javascript coding.

Thanx in advance,
kvj

Comment: http://www.jsonlint.com/
hope this link will help you.

Comment: It may help them check if there JSON is well formed, but it doesn't necessarily answer the 3 questions.

Comment: answers the 1st question though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) JSON spec says *use double quotes*.

> String (double-quoted Unicode with backslash escaping)

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example).

2) `eval()` is not a JSON parser, but a JavaScript evaluator. It will run your string as if it were JavaScript.

3) In JavaScript, they have the same meaning. Just be consistent. I personally use `'` because I sometimes deal with serialised HTML and I use `"` for my attribute values.